# Android - What debug.keystore file is IntelliJ signing my app with?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-mapview, keystore, signing

I'm trying to debug why I can't get `MapView` to work in debug mode, and it seems like the app is not being signed with the `debug.keystore` file that I have created an API key against.  The only version of a file named `debug.keystore` on my system is in the `C:\Users\<user>\.android` folder as expected, however after removing this file completely and then rebuilding the unsigned app, it still runs in debug mode and does not regenerate this file as though it is signing with a different cert.  Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out there was another `debug.keystore` in `android-sdk\\.android` folder.  Not sure why I didn't see this when I searched the drive before, but now it is the only one on the machine and sure enough does get regenerated when rebuilding.  Don't know why it is not looking in `C:\Users` like documented, but creating a map api against this keystore does fix my `MapView` problem.

Answer (score 8):

Please double check that you've removed the `debug.keystore` file from the correct user account:

```
c:\Users\%USERNAME%\.android\debug.keystore
```

On my system it's re-generated as soon as I delete it and rebuild the project in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: aka `%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`